# CSS / jQuery Dropdown menu. Z-Index not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

I have a drop down menu that is attached to a fixed navigation bar.  Similar to the one the current Twitter design uses.

Here is link to this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/JDahp/3/ (This has been updated to be far more simple than previous iterations)

I use jQuery to make the menu appear / disappear which works fine.  The menu animates OVER the toolbar as opposed to under it.

I cannot understand why z-index isn't overriding the usual visual stacking for the drop down menu?

Here are the relevant CSS properties

```
#top-stuff{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:12;
    width:100%;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

A cut down version of the HTML:

```
<div id="top-stuff">
    <a href="" class="optionslinka">Options</a>
    <div class="dropdown" id="optionsdropdown">
        <!-- Drop down content is here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what browser are you using here and can you link to an example?

Comment: I have tested in both IE and FF - both have the same issue. Cannot provide an example easily it's code for a client that is not online.

Comment: you can put a prototype here: jsfiddle.net

Comment: yea js fiddle would be very handy!

Comment: Done, looks rubbish but it shows the issue!

Comment: ah right i see will see about solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is a little complex and busy for me to look through, but I think it's likely your issue relates to the z-index bug that IE is known for (but has affected other browsers as well).

Basically, if `z-index` isn't defined on all of your parent containers, then each `z-index` will start a new 'stacking context`, meaning they will not overlap properly.  Think of 2 decks of cards rather than one.

Try setting `position:relative;z-index:auto;` on all of the parent containers above `.dropdown` (or any other `position:` like `absolute` etc)

Some resources to learn more:
Drop Down Menu Issues: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/
An in depth look:  http://caffeineoncode.com/2010/07/the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

A similar issue to yours:  http://richa.avasthi.name/blogs/tepumpkin/2008/01/11/ie7-lessons-learned/

> you’ll notice that any positioned element, with any z-index, that is located lower down in the code than the menus will appear above the menus—no matter what z-index the menu is given—exactly the opposite of what you want to happen.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice but doing this still doesn't work - I updated fiddler with a simpler version of the code

Comment: I'm lost as hell too.  I trimmed your fiddle down to the meat, and every combination that _should_ word, isn't.  Here is what I got to and got fed up with it not playing nice. http://jsfiddle.net/ecSv8/

Answer (score 0):

i removed all the z-index bits and just put

```
z-index: -1;
```

on this

```
#optionsdropdown
```

which seemed to work i believe the problem stems from the containing element having position fixed..

Comment: If I set it to -1 it goes behind content on the page :(

Comment: yea thought that may happen you seem to have several div's which dont really do anything, clearing them out may help

Comment: They are there for other content to go in, I stripped all that out for the purposes of the demo